# Convert postgres column type from enum to array of enums

Tags: postgresql, alembic

I currently have a table called employees having column access_level of type enum (accessLevel). But now I want to provide the employee multiple access_levels so now I need to convert the datatype from enum to array of enum.

I ran the following query

```
ALTER TABLE employees ALTER COLUMN access_level TYPE accessLevel[] USING access_level::accessLevel[]
```

But in response getting the following error 
`ERROR:  cannot cast type accessLevel to accessLevel[]  LINE 1: ... access_level TYPE accessLevel[] USING access_level::accessLev...`

Comment: A properly normalized model without an enum and classic one-to-many relationship might be a better solution in the long run

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I initially started with the same approach but then I realised this will end up creating too many rows so I stick to this methodology. It'll be great if you can help me understand the downsides of this approach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast a single value to an array, you need to build a new array:

```
ALTER TABLE employees 
    ALTER COLUMN access_level TYPE accessLevel[] 
    USING array[access_level];
```